# Vue deletes last item in array and not ID

Tags: vue.js

I have a loop with items in a array. When I try to delete a item it's deleting the last item instead of the selected item. Can anybody help me with this?

Demo can be viewed here:

https://jsfiddle.net/frontero/f3cLqkt0/1/

```
<div id="form">


<div v-for="(item, index) in items" class="mt-3" :list="index" :key="item.index">
                        <div class="form-row">
                            <div class="col-md-11">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="video[]" placeholder="For example https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sds-EeX1s  or  https://vimeo.com/ondemand/horse">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-1"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-light w-100" :data-index="index" @click.prevent="deleteVideo(index)"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i> Delete</button></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <button class="btn btn-secondary mt-3" @click.prevent="addVideo"><i class="fas fa-plus-square"></i> Add a extra video</button>

          </div>


new Vue({
        el: '#form',
        data: {
            name: '',
            items: []
        },
        methods: {
            addVideo(){
                console.log(this.items);
                this.items.push({
                    value: ''
                });
            },
            deleteVideo(index){
                console.log(index);
                this.items.splice(index,1);
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

`item.index` is undefined. So you track items by `undefined` field and vue doesn't know how associate data with rendered nodes.

Use a valid key (id of item) or hack - item itself
https://jsfiddle.net/82dsnyg0/
 :)

`<div v-for="(item, index) in items" :key="item">...`

Vue needs to know how map "item" into "html" (and how take html node from js-item).
Without keys result htmls are "equal" (for Vue) and Vue is trying to reuse already rendered html nodes (that is why the last node looks like removed).

With keys vue is able to take html-node by js-item and know which html-node should be deleted when js-item is removed.

**So NEVER use `v-for` without propper `:key`s!**

Comment: I suggest you also say how this causes problems, namely the fact that all the buttons are the same from vue's perspective, and thus it looks like it's removed the last button

Comment: Vue needs to know how map "item" into "html". Result htmls are "equal" (for vue) without proper keys and vue is trying to reuse already rendered html nodes. With keys vue is able to take html-node by js-data.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like you have item.index defined anywhere. The idea for :key is to use a unique identifier for the object to keep it synced up. If the items are unique you should use `:key="item"`.

Take a look at the doc for more details:
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#key